# ArrayList.RemoveRange

Tags: c#

Хочу определить время, затраченное на удаление элементов коллекции, но почему-то выдает независимо от кол-во элементов 0 мсек

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        Console.Write("Введит количество элементов коллекции: ");
        int collectionLength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        stopWatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < collectionLength; i++)
            al.Add(CreateRandomString());
        foreach (var s in al)
            Console.Write("{0}\t", s);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Время заполнения коллекции: {0}",stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
        Console.WriteLine("Количество элементов в коллекции: {0}", collectionLength);
        sw.Start();
        al.RemoveRange(0,collectionLength);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(al.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Время удаления: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    static string CreateRandomString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var randomIndex = r.Next(chars.Length);
            sb.Append(chars[randomIndex]);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: сколько элементов вы вводили?

Comment: Потому что время на удаление элементов существенно меньше миллисекунды, разумеется. 2016 год на дворе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если заглянуть в [исходники ArrayList.RemoveRange](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,611), можно увидеть следующий процесс удаления

```
if (count > 0) {
    int i = _size;
    _size -= count;
    if (index < _size) {
        Array.Copy(_items, index + count, _items, index, _size - index);
    }
    while (i > _size) _items[--i] = null;
    _version++;
}
```

То есть фактически удаление заключается в простом пробегании по всем элементам и присваивании `null`. Это в принципе довольно быстрая операция. Поэтому чтобы получить время удаления больше миллисекунд нужно значительное количество элементов.

Кроме свойства [ElapsedMilliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx), у [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) есть так же свойство
[`ElapsedTicks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks(v=vs.110).aspx) - получающее общее затраченное время в тактах таймера, измеренное текущим экземпляром.

Comment: перед тем как создать вопрос пробовал на 500,000 элементах, дало 0 мсек. сейчас попробывал на 1,000,000 дало 1 мсек)

Comment: @cruim, если бы смотрели в отладчике, могли бы увидеть, что значение какое-нибудь `0.000045` и при выводе оно просто обрезалось